# pick elements from the list randomly in uniform distribution without replacement

Tags: python-3.x, list, random, statistics, uniform-distribution

I have a list that ranges from 0 to 30

```
arr = range(0,30)
```

I need to pick a sample of "m" elements from the list using uniform distribution without replacement. I used **random.uniform()** which gives the random value in float.

Can anyone tell me how to pick the "m" elements from the given list randomly using uniform distribution without replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `random.sample` to take a sample without replacement

```
# Python3 program to demonstrate
# the use of sample() function

# import random
from random import sample

# Prints list of random items of given length
arr = range(0,30)

m=5

mysamp = sample(arr,m)
```

Comment: Is it sampled in uniform distribution?

Comment: @merkle Yes - each element is equally likely to be picked, so it is a discrete uniform distribution on the set of 5 unique numbers between 0 and 30